# Contract class and SysOperation framework

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a contract/UIBuilder class for a SSRS report. I want to use the same Contaract/UIBuilder class to generate  data in excel.

I have came across http://www.artofcreation.be/2011/08/22/ax2012-sysoperation-part-1-data-contracts-and-service-operations/ post. Where i found that services class is used.

I have found examples where some uses services class and a few dont.

Is it really important to use services?
Also what is the advantage of using it?

Comment: Your question is a little vague on the purpose. Could you be more specific?

Comment: It seems like you are asking 2 different questions: 1. how do i use the same classes for ssrs and sysoperation and 2. why use sysoperation at all...

Answer (score 0):

[How to Use a Report Data Provider Class in a Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731917.aspx)?

The same contract can be used in several reports by specifying it with the `SRSReportParameterAttribute` attribute in the reports:

```
[
    SRSReportQueryAttribute('Cust'),
    SRSReportParameterAttribute(classstr(SrsRDPContractSample))
]
public class SrsRdpSampleClass extends SRSReportDataProviderBase
{
    TmpCustTableSample tmpCust;
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply but the report I am creating is an excel and not a ssrs report so i want to use the contract class as parameter in the excel class.

Comment: You must first explain what an Excel report is in the first place.

Comment: actually i am trying to generate data in excel after getting parameters through UIBuilder and contract class.. I have done the same using dialog. I may have to make use of SysOperation framework but I ma not sure how.

Comment: Then go learn: http://amazingax.wordpress.com/tag/sysoperation-framework-ax2012/
By the force of Google ...

Comment: in the link i see the use of service.. is it necessary. I just need the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to skip the 1st question because you should just try and you will have your answer as to whether it works...

the second question, you have a good blog post already--but also check out:

http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2011/08/from-runbase-to-sysoperation-business.html

and of course the ms links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg862488.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29215

high points include:

- server side operation
- separating ui elements from contract and logic
- batchable